# Can autocorrelation be observed in a non-ordered data?

Tags: regression, time-series, econometrics

Autocorrelation means that the error terms are serially correlated. However, if we have an un-ordered dataset, we can always shuffle the data to change the serial ordering then we can change the covariance matrix of errors.

This question has startled me to some extent. If we have a dataset that is not ordered by time (purely non-time series data), we should never theoretically observe a serial correlation.

Comment: Dependence can arise in many contexts other than time (or space), such as individuals within households, patients treated by the same doctor or at the same hospital.

Comment: @DrStrangeLove: You'll benefit from reading on clustered standard errors https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustered_standard_errors

Comment: @NickCox What if we have no information on hierarchy of data? We just have a series of observations. Will shuffling or randomly sorting those observations can remove autocorrelation?

Comment: If observations are dependent, or not, shuffling them to a different order makes no difference to model fit. If it did textbooks would be full of earnings that sort order matters, but a fit $y = Xb$ doesn’t depend on the order of rows and columns in a dataset. The only calculations affected by sort order are serial correlations of residuals based on taking the order literally, which will be correct if that defines (e.g.) a time order.

Answer (score 2):

> Autocorrelation means that the error terms are serially correlated.

Not exactly, autocorrelation of order $k$ can be defined as $C(y_t,y_{t-k})$, error terms are not involved.

> Can autocorrelation be observed in a non-ordered data?

No, ordering is needed.

Terms like autocorrelation and serial correlation make sense in time series or in some stochastic process sense. Therefore some ordering is needed, usually time ordering. Indeed you have to manage the dataset carefully, ordering matters a lot.

As opposite, for general correlation no specific ordering is needed.

Comment: Space ordering can be important: there are many simple cases in Earth and environmental science with observations on a profile or transect.  However, even with one-dimensional spatial series, there isn't usually a distinction equivalent to that between past and future. More subtle are cases such as state or country data for a given time where dependence between observations can be an issue, but it's not captured by an autocorrelation function but needs some other approach, e.g. comparing each state or country with its neighbours.

Comment: Indeed what you mention can be topic for the so called 'spatial Econometrics', in which the concept of serial correlation is replaced by spatial correlation.

Comment: Spatial problems arise in many fields outside econometrics.